# How do I implement this protocol in struct

Tags: swift, design-patterns, protocols, abstract-factory

I'm new to Swift and I want to create an abstract factory for db access.
Here is my protocol

```
protocol IDAOFactory
{
  associatedtype DAO: IDAO

  func createAccountDAO<DAO: IAccountDAO>() -> DAO
}

struct RealmFactory: IDAOFactory
{

}

protocol IDAO
{
   associatedtype T
   func save(object: T)
}

protocol IAccountDAO : IDAO
{

}

struct AccountDAORealm: IAccountDAO
{

}
```

How to implement the IDAOFactory in struct RealmFactory and IAccountDAO in struct AccountDAORealm?
Can anybody help?

Comment: Why a struct? Structs are value objects, not reference objects.

Comment: you mean using Class will be better?

Comment: It's your decision, but structs are passed as _values_ so everyone calling your factory will get a different struct. Every time you pass a struct to a function, a copy of the struct will be created.

Comment: Also you will not be able to inherit struct if you need later.

Comment: thanks for your suggesstion

Answer (score 2):

Generics in Swift have many restrictions especially when used in protocols and implemented in struct. Let's wait until Swift 3 :)

I use protocols and derived classes or generics with classes but mixing protocols generics and structs makes a headache in Swift 2 (C# generics in much more convenient)

I played with your code in playground, here it is

```
protocol IDAOFactory
{
    associatedtype DAO: IDAO

    func createAccountDAO<DAO: IAccountDAO>() -> DAO
}

protocol IDAO
{
    init()
    associatedtype T
    func save(object: T)
}

protocol IAccountDAO : IDAO
{
    init()
}

public class AccountDAORealm: IAccountDAO
{
    var data: String = ""

    required public init() {
        data = "data"
    }

    func save(object: AccountDAORealm) {
        //do save
    }
}

let accountDAORealm = AccountDAORealm() 
//As you see accountDAORealm is constructed without any error

struct RealmFactory: IDAOFactory
{
    func createAccountDAO<AccountDAORealm>() -> AccountDAORealm {
        return  AccountDAORealm() //but here constructor gives error
    }
}
```

Comment: seems implement in class will be a better way.it is a headache for swift syntax